# How should self-answers that copy another answer be flagged?

Tags: discussion, flags

Every once in a while a new user posts a self-answer where they re-post the solution to their problem from another answer to their question instead of accepting that answer. Most likely just because they don't understand (yet) how SO works, not because they try to plagiarize existing content.

How should such answers be flagged? "Not an answer" doesn't feel appropriate, but on the other hand using a custom moderator flag seems like a waste of moderators' time for something this trivial. Should they be flagged at all?

Comment: I assure you such a thing is anything but trivial. It doesn't matter if the user didn't *mean* to steal content; it's still plagiarism.

Comment: Just downvote them?

Comment: "Hey dude, welcome to SO. This is not how we do things here, accept the other answer instead."

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Flag the post for moderator attention, and say something like;

> OP has copied [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341124/how-should-self-answers-that-copy-another-answer-be-flagged) and posted it as their own, rather than accepting it.

... we process a lot of these.

In general, NAA flags should only be used in situations where the post is not an attempt to answer the question. Since, in these situations the post *is* an answer (albeit a  duplicated one), you'll likely find any NAA flags used in this situation being declined.

Comment: Do answers which both refer and simplify an existing answer also fall under this rule?