# Should I accept an not-so-good answer, or improve it myself, then accept my own answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, self-answer

Sometimes our question gets answers which are not so good, but surely solved our problems.

Should I just accept the answer that solves my problem? Or should I write my own answer with improved, more detailed information, nicer format, then accept my own answer?

Comment: see this post: [How should self-answers that copy another answer be flagged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341124/how-should-self-answers-that-copy-another-answer-be-flagged)

Comment: @MichaelGaskill That is certainly not the same issue.

Comment: Sure, that's why I didn't mark it as a duplicate.  What it does tell you is that self-answering based on information from another answer may get you mod-flagged, and isn't likely to go in your favor.  Be cautious about going that route.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill Very considerate. I was misunderstanding before.