# Asker substantially copied my answer into their own, and then accepted their answer

Tags: discussion, specific-question, etiquette, self-answer, attribution

I answered the question [Compute 2 subqueries then group by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787671/compute-2-subqueries-then-group-by-date-mysql). Shortly after, the asker posted an answer of their own, which they admits was taken from my answer, and then accepted this copy answer.

What can I do with such case? I think this is very rude behaviour.

Comment: *"answered somebody's question and that person ...  upvoted only his answer"* - Users can't upvote their own posts

Comment: Even when it's answer to his own question? I saw that after his comment, his answer had 1 upvote.

Comment: Even then, users can never upvote their own posts, only accept their own answers. Their answer has no upvotes.

Comment: Someone downvoted then, because I'm sure that had 1 upvote.

Comment: @Tajniak Then the upvoter retracted it. There are no votes in either direction on the answer.

Comment: Nobody has downvoted it, it has 0 upvotes and 0 downvotes: [See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FluuG.png) (And because it hasn't been edited, the upvoter must have retracted it in the grace period)

Comment: They can't upvote at all and clearly answer that 100% applicable to they specific case is "most useful"... One thing you can claim here is plagiarism as your whole answer is copy-pasted with very weak attempt to attribution...

Comment: So somebody has reverted his upvote. But can I do something for such insolent behaviour? Or just humbly accepted this kind of users on SO?

Comment: @Tajniak You can try to use a mod flag (the "in need of moderator intervention" option in the flag menu) and explain that it is just copied from your answer and as such is more of a thank you than an actual helpful addition to the answers already there. Other than that there's not much to do besides downvote and move along. FWIW, I would not call this rude or insolent, maybe a bit unfair, but not much more than that.

Comment: Related questions: [Is it appropriate to answer one's own question with code derived from another answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107001/997587), [What to do if an asker makes a self-answer based on a previously-accepted other answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156239/997587), [Should I include the working code after I have resolved an issue using more than one of the answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305906/11107541)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Some new users don't understand how the site works immediately.

In that case, it seems that the question asker copied your answer and accepted their own, like people do in a forum. So I wouldn't call that plagiarism, just misuse of the site.

Note that the acceptance of a self answer doesn't reward the person who asked/answered (accepting an answer from *someone else* awards 2 rep). The answer hasn't been upvoted, so at the present time, the answerer has no interest in answering with a copy of your answer.

I deleted the self-answer, advising the asker to accept your answer instead.

*Side note*: I also saw your flag about this from 2 hours ago. We have a lot of custom flags to process. So if you flagged and nothing happens in the next minutes, don't hold your breath. Creating a meta post is sometimes informative for others, but from now on if such situation happens again, just flag.

Comment: Thank you. I'm also fresh contributor and don't know all rules yet. I accidentally flagged post wrongly and flagged it second time for another purpose.

Answer (score -9):

In this very specific case, I think an edit would have been more appropriate, but *in general*, deriving answers from other answers, and giving a self-answer deriving from another answer with adjustments to show one's (the asker's) final solution is allowed, and it is not "very rude behaviour".

Now that I've reached 10k rep and can see deleted posts, I can see that their self-answer is mostly the same as the answer it derives from (yours), except that it adds back some contextual code that was there in their question post. That's why I think an edit to your post would have been appropriate.

This same question/topic has essentially been covered six times already- three times on meta.stackexchange.com (2011, 2012, 2014), and three times on meta.stackoverflow.com (2014, 2015, 2019). All those older Q&A have fairly highly upvoted answers saying that in *general*, this is *not* unacceptable behaviour.

I.e., there is a stronger, longer-standing precedent that such behaviour is not unacceptable or rude.

Here are those posts and their verdicts:

- [What to do if an asker makes a self-answer based on a previously-accepted other answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156239/997587) (MSE 2012)

  This Q&A itself should satisfy the discussion here. It covers three different cases of "augmented answers":

  > If the answer differs substantially from the originally accepted answer, or combines several different answers into a single one, then I don't see a problem. The OP apparently found his answer more useful.
  >
  > If the new answer is essentially the same as the original answer, I would leave a comment stating that you feel it is bad form to hijack someone else's answer, and downvote his new answer.
  >
  > If it's basically a copy/paste of another answer without attribution (crediting the original author), you can flag for removal, citing plagiarism.
  >
  > - @user102937
- [Addition to answer. Self answer or comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388037/11107541) (MSO 2019)

  > Self-answer. Your addition is a standalone response to the answer. Be sure to add attribution to whoever provided most of the answer for you. - [@Makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1079354)

  > I’d accept the other answer, upvote it, then post your own answer, which should start out immediately and explicitly saying “Building on @OtherUser’s very helpful answer (link to his answer), I created a more complete solution this: ...”. That way credit where credit is due, and the community benefits also from a more comprehensive answer, while giving the original answer the head start it earned. - [@Dan Bron](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2562182)
- [What's the right way to self-answer if other answers assisted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262210/11107541) (MSO 2014)

  A bit contrary to Dan Bron, this post with lots of upvotes says:

  > Marking an answer as accepted is supposed to represent that that answer ultimately solved your problem. Marking an answer that did not solve your problem (and leaving it that way) will mislead future users who are also having the same problem, and are trying to find a solution.
  >
  > What I would do in your case is to just link to the other person's answer, mentioning that their answer inspired yours, and other people may give it a few upvotes then. You can even make your own answer into a community wiki, if you feel that you personally don't deserve any reputation from upvotes for (partially) using someone else's idea. - @user456814
- [Is it appropriate to answer one's own question with code derived from another answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107001/997587) (MSE 2011)

  > If the user gives credit to the sources, why not? At first I thought they might be gaming the system for points, but since that isn't what's happening, it should be OK. - [@Caffeinated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/164243)

  > It is actually a pretty common scenario that the answers help resolve the question but don't show the whole picture. So I actually consider it good if the OP posts the complete solution that resolved his problem again. Of course only as long as he credits sources for this solution. - [@WladimirPalant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/163275)
- [OP answers his/her own question without acknowledging the help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229196/997587) (MSE 2014)

  > There's really nothing wrong with this. The author of the first answer didn't edit the changes into his own answer, so I think it's perfectly within reason for the OP to post their own answer with a working example. - [@BillTheLizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1288)

  Important note: I find that answer incomplete because it should really say that the self-answer in question should attribute sources where appropriate/necessary.
- [Should I include the working code after I have resolved an issue using more than one of the answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305906/11107541) (MSO 2015)

  > I would indeed suggest to post an own answer. Give attribution to the users you derived an answer from and make sure it is more than just a code dump of the working code. The answer should really stand on its own.
  >
  > I would also suggest accepting the answer that helped you best if your work is a derivative from that answer, not your own. An exception can be made if your post is much better than the work you derived your answer from.
  >
  > Never post working code as a comment or an edit of your question. That isn't the place for answers.
  >
  > - [@PatrickHofman](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/993547)

To sum up, in general, this is ok as long as they attribute the existing answer they based their self-answer off of. Contributed content here on Stack Exchange is all licensed under [CC-BY-SA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license#Four_rights). Yes, they do have the option to edit the existing answer and collaborate with the author of the existing answer to get it up to where they'd like it to be, but as far as I'm aware, there is no official rule or community-accepted guideline that says they have to. And remember that edits should not change the meaning of the post or conflict with the original author's intent, so there are actually a lot of things you *can't* do in an edit that you *can* do by posting a new derivative answer.

I can't say that if someone made an "augmented", properly attributed version of an answer I wrote and got a bunch of rep for it, I wouldn't be irked. Of coursed I'd be a little irked: I would rather have them edit my answer so I can get more fake internet points! But unless there's a strong case for the augmented answer to be an edit to my hypothetical answer (such as the augmentation being very minor and not diverging from the intent/meaning of my post), I would have to let it be because it's allowed. I would hold no grudges, and neither would I think of the augmenter as rude. Any rep they get for it would technically be deserved, since they provided value that the other answer didn't, and remember that there's nothing stopping the other answerer from augmenting their own answer based on the derivative answer to make even further improvements as long as it follows the CC-BY-SA license.

[If the self-answer is an exact copy with no attribution (or even with attribution), obviously, it should be flagged.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341124/11107541)

Comment: While this is technically true, it still *may* end up deleted if it has no original content, even if properly cited.

Comment: @KevinB yep. That's covered by the second and third paragraphs of user102937's quoted section.

Comment: It seems like this answer is descriptively accurate, even if people would prefer to see such situations handled differently. starball has accurately identified 3 prior instances of the exact same question, asked on Meta.SE, and has accurately summarized answers from there.  (Do people dislike the existing answers on those other questions?  Do people not like the summary at the end of this answer?  The answer seems like an accurate statement of existing guidelines on meta -- is it that people don't like the existing guidelines on Meta.SE and prefer a different policy here?)

Comment: @starball Note what the other answer here says: "In that case, it seems that the question asker copied your answer and accepted their own, like people do in a forum."