# Asker de-accepted my answer, wrote and accepted his own which is mostly a copy/paste of mine. Should I do something?

Tags: discussion

An asker asked [a question about TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74784200/3757232), I [answered it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74786352/3757232), got a couple of upvotes, and the user accepted it.

Now he's un-accepted it and [posted his own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74787642/3757232). The only difference AFAICT is that he used string enums instead of the default integer enum. The user can accept whatever answer he wants; I'm a little more concerned about the copy/paste aspect.

Is this ok (i.e., is his answer different enough from mine to not constitute plagiarism)? If not, should I flag for mod attention or something?

Comment: “Is this ok (i.e. is his answer different enough from mine to not constitute plagiarism)?” - Only so many ways to implement to create an Enum of strings, code is hardly, original. Your answer is actually based on the author’s own code.

Comment: But at the same time, it's the same answer, just reposted... I don't think it's plagiarism at all but it's a weird behavior from the OP.

Comment: For an answer to be useful I think it should lead to OP (and hopefully others) to a solution that is helpful.  Yours does that.  It doesn't need to be (and usually isn't) the *exact code* the OP will use. He was able to tweak the syntax slightly to satisfy certain requirements (which I don't believe were even mentioned in the question) - which is good for him but I don't think it is reason enough to unaccept your answer.  He is certainly free to do so and I wouldn't call this plagiarism, but it's not really contributing much and is also a bit annoying.

Comment: Related: [Asker substantially copied my answer into his own, and then accepted his](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397556/8239061)

Comment: Possibly relevant: [What to do with answers that are copy and paste of other answers here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311662/8239061)

Comment: Looks like this asker has [one other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72294510/error-missing-required-argument-count-for-minting-please-provide-the-argument/) and did almost the exact same thing. First accepted another user's answer that lead them to a solution, then posted their own variant and unaccepted original answer. In both cases his copy was only useful for solving *a different issue* he encountered that isn't even mentioned in the question. I'm still not sure if any rules are being broken here but it's pretty distasteful.

Comment: @EatenbyaGrue yeah it left a bad taste in my mouth but I figured I'd ask on meta before just flagging it.

Comment: An interpretation is using Stack Overflow as a forum: The "answer" is a response to your answer.

Comment: But it is hard to imagine the question is not a duplicate. How can such a simple question not have been asked before among the existing [203,713 TypeScript questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript)?

Comment: The (un-)acceptance part is perfectly fine, everyone has complete freedom there. The duplication of the answer though, that would be pollution. But we have to assume the best, it does seem like the OP considers their answer to be different because they make the distinction of it being a "string enum" rather than an "enum". Something tells me they meant it to be a const enum actually. Just another person using Stack Overflow as they please, probably.

Comment: @JaredSmith I was not meant to upvote my own answer. I just wanted to let the other users know what works with your answer. Sorry for that. I am not much familiar with stackoverflow, I am new bee here.

Comment: @Tusharkharat I was wondering if it was something like that, which is why I asked for the community's opinion on the situation here rather than just downvoting your answer and flagging it for the mods to delete. No worries.