Is it plagiarism if my solution is reposted with a minor change that makes it work with an older version?
Backstory: Some years ago I posted a solution for an old, unanswered question. Nothing happened for a couple of months, but then the question author commented on my answer to note that is doesn't work with his version. Two minutes after that they proceeded to post a slightly modified version of my answer and marked it as the accepted answer. They did not credit my answer in any way.
So they were clearly aware of my answer before posting their version.
The difference in answers roughly looks like this (obfuscated to disconnect it from the actual question). I tend to think that this is plagiarism, but I'm not entirely sure, since the edit does alter behavior in older versions.
My answer
# An example text taken from the question {.foo .bar}

Their answer
# An example text taken from the question {.foo .bar .baz}


My version also comes with a paragraph that explains why the answer works, but that's possibly beside the point.

I would say no, but I might be wrong.

Looking at the actual posts (For anyone wondering the obfuscated answers here pretty much match the actual content being talked about). I'd say no it's not plagiarism.

It could be, but it's impossible to make a judgement without the two candidates to review, and your example doesn't help me.

I mean, providing some credit is probably the most ethical choice. But "plagiarism" is pretty strong.

Put another way, how else could the OP possibly have written that single line of markup in such a way that you would not consider it plagiarism?

Hard to tell with the content obfuscated. Give us a link and we can weigh in for real.

plagiarism discussion aside, if it clearly has a semantic difference (and especially if it has a possible benefit), I don't see an issue. it would be a nice thing if they said "here's a version of tarleb's answer made to work with version X", but I haven't heard of that being a rule here. they could have commented on your answer, but I think it's fine and maybe even good that they posted a competing answer. if they suggested this as an edit to your answer post, as a reviewer, I'd probably skip and hope that you as the post owner would decide whether or not to accept.

honestly, this gives me vibes of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397556/11107541. a fun read. you can find one of my most unpopular MSO answer posts there.

@starball your most unpopular is only at -8 (at the time of writing)? That's at worst divisive, so I guess you're pretty popular :)

I think the key question is whether they copied the general idea, or a nontrivial specific implementation.  Put another way: is it clearly primarily copy-pasting a nontrivial implementation of yours, or would anyone trying to convey the same technique have written largely the same thing?
For your example, if your answer was {.foo .bar} and theirs was {.foo .bar .baz}, that's too trivial to be plagiarism (assuming they didn't also copy your written explanation).  Anyone trying to convey the idea of "add these 2/3 classes" would write, roughly, that.
If your answer looked more like (meaningless nonsense courtesy of ChatGPT):
a, b = 42, "baz"; c = lambda x: x[::-1] * 2; d = [c(b) for _ in range(a)]
class X: pass; x = X(); x.y = sum(ord(ch) for ch in b) % a
e = lambda n: "end" if n < 1 else e(n-1) + str(n)
print("Output:", e(len(d[0]))[:10])

and their answer was the same code block, but with str(n) changed to str(n, encoding="UTF-8"), then that requires your answer to be properly credited. If such credit is provided, it can still be posted as a separate answer as long as it's a meaningful change (which the example of updating it to work on other versions would be).

TIL: it's not actually possible to do class X: pass; x = X() on the same line (without a prior definition) with a semicolon like that. It's valid Python syntax, but results in a NameError. (With that fixed, the interesting part of the output is end123456.)

To add some context {.foo} was already part of the question so the only thing OPs answer added to the code was .bar. Also both bar and baz are documented attributes (But the documentation is difficult to find). Also no, the asker didn't copy OP's explanation in their answer.

Makes perfect sense, thanks! I'll chalk it off as "mildly bad style, but acceptable".
